# Parent component re-rendering child components multiple times ReactJS

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

I am relatively new(ish) to React so still trying to learn best practice etc..

I am currently creating a dashboard style application that has multiple 'widgets' displaying various data. I have a parent component 'Dashboard' and this renders each of the 'Widget' components (which are dumb components) and the data is passed via props.

Now the problem I have is that in my 'Dashboard' component I am doing one ajax call to get the data for each Widget, on success of each ajax call I am calling setState() and pushing data in.

This appears to be correct from a design pattern perspective, but obviously calling setState will causes cascade re-renders, so each widget is being re-rendered in my case 10 times (as I have 10 widgets).

What am I doing so wrong here? Is my app now a candidate for Flux or Redux type architecture?

**Edit:** Code below

**Parent component**

```
/**
 * Ajax calls (10 different calls, wont list them, all very similar)
 */
getRecent: function (url, limit) {

    $.get(url, function (res) {

        var data = res.response;
        var products = [];

        if (data.itemListInfo.numberOfItems > 0) {
            for (var i = 0, j = limit; i < j; i++) {
                products.push({
                    name: data.userItems[i].product.name,
                    itemCode: data.userItems[i].product.itemCode,
                    img: data.userItems[i].product.thumbnailImage,
                });
            }

        }

        // Obviously this is causing render() to fire
        this.setState({
            recent: {
                numberOfItems: data.itemListInfo.numberOfItems,
                products: products
            }
        });

        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#account-recent .loading').fadeOut();
        }, 500);

    }.bind(this));

},
componentDidMount: function () {
    this.getReviews(this.config.reviews.url); // causes a render()
    this.getRecent('/api/user/purchases/list', 3); // causes a render()
    this.getRecommended('/api/user/recommendations/list', 3); // causes render()
    this.getPreferences('/api/user/preferences/list'); //causes render()
    // More ajax calls here....
},
render: function () {
    return (
        <Reviews data={this.state.reviews}/>
        <Recommended data={this.state.recommended}/>
        <RecentlyPurchased data={this.state.recent}/>
        <Preferences data={this.state.preferences}/>
    )
}
```

If I was to put a console.log('rendering...') in one of the children's render methods it would display a number of times depending on what position it is in the ajax call stack

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Comment: If you do need to hit 5 APIs (or one API five times) to get each widget's information, then do that in each widget. If you can get it all in one bunch, do it in the parent. Or you could use `Promise.all([])` and wait for all requests to come back before updating state. But really, yeah put it in a redux store.

Comment: @DavidGilbertson yeah I originally started off doing the calls in the individual components but then read somewhere that all data is better passed via props from the parent to 'dumb' components, so went this route

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned, you store information about all widgets in parent widget, so when the state changes, it triggers children update, what is expected behavior. Since there are no code, it is hard to identify your case, but there are some for you:

1. Implement`shouldComponentUpdate` method, so widget will be updated only if it receives changed props.
2. Do 1 ajax call to get the information for all the widgets, so you would have only 1 call and 1 update.
3. You can use redux or mobx and connect your widgets to a state, then it will be re-rendered only if the props passed to the widget were changed.

It would be easier to help if you write more code.

Comment: Hi Ross - yes I understand why it is doing it, I am at work now so will add some code in a few minutes. I tried implementing shouldComponentUpdate but the component never receives the initial data (because I'm guessing setState has already happened 3 or 4 times already before it hits that widget). Unfortunately I have to call multiple endpoints to get different data. Maybe I could do each AJAX call then push into an array then when all ajax calls complete I can set the sate once. seems overkill? I will post code